# POST request to node.js script running locally

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is probably a really basic question.

I'm new to node.js.

I'm writing a script which receives an HTTP POST request. I'm going to be deploying to Heroku, but while I'm testing locally how do I make POST requests to the script?

Thanks.

Comment: You must be using `relative` path for API, make it `absolute` and test..

Comment: I would personally make test HTML file from where I do POST request to the server, XMLHttpRequest, $.ajax, $http etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chrome extension called postman.

Comment: Nobody really knows, stackoverflow is strange that way. I'll balance it

Comment: Postman is great – it also lets you save requests and request suites for faster debugging.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're on unix (OSX, Linux, BSD) or have an environment where you can download/use unix tools (cygwin, git bash) you can use `curl`:

   ```
   curl -XPOST http://localhost/my/app -d 'data you want to post'
   ```
2. If you're using Google Chrome or you're on a Mac install [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)